# Error when trying to install libraries or update certificates

Tags: python

This is the message i get when i get when i try to install libraries:

- certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

Then it also gives me the message :

You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.1.2 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\xxx...\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I was trying to install libraries for python, i tried also with anaconda and got the same error.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once regarding the ssl error. I was able to solve it by installing these two libraries:

- pip_system_certs
- python-certifi-win32

Otherwise I would suggest upgradind pip to the newer version

Comment: You should probably add instructions on how to install them withput `pip` being able to connect to PyPi

Comment: Yes but the problem remains because whenever i try to uptade or install i get the same error